# URL drops :8888 from localhost

Tags: url, routes, mamp

I'm running Craft CMS with MAMP at `localhost:8888`.

When I pass in a URL with `{{ entry.title }}`, I get http://localhost/news/2016/we-just-installed-craft which gives me a 404 until I manually put in the `:8888` after localhost.

Am I missing something in the set up here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try and put the port in your siteUrl config param:

```
'siteUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888',
```

Alternatively you might be able to use this though haven't tested it (I believe the php server variable uses the server name & port number):

```
'localhost' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    'devMode' => true,
    'cacheMethod' => 'file'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using 'siteUrl' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] inside my config file fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you required to run port 8888? If not, you can set the port to 80 in MAMP and this would resolve the issue. I know this is not really a fix for your problem but it might be a potential work-around.